# Need help understanding xmpp xeps

Tags: android, xmpp

First I am completely new to programming world.

I am trying to develop an app which will also have a website. I want to have a chat feature in it . After googling I found xmpp servers such as openfire jabber, etc and smack and like libraries. I understand that the the xmpp server can implement general chat features but do I need to install the xep files to get to use xeps?
What do I need to do on the server side and client side to implement the xeps?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to implement core XEPs on the server so no need to worry there (especially as you are only doing chat).

I'd suggest prosody.im as a quick easy server to set up and use rather than openfire.

I'd then look at the asmack library if you are doing android development.

Cheers, Lloyd.

Comment: Ic thx becoz it's quite confusing! Just to be clear if I want to implement the xeps I have to simply add the XML code on the client side and that should be fine?

Comment: Your server has to support it too. Most of the maintained ones will :)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you this book: 
Professional XMPP Programming with Javascript and JQuery - Jack Moffitt

I'm building single chat an application javascript+strophejs just reading this book.

Good luck.

Comment: oh but this one is for javascript and jquery is there any book for android development?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but see this tutorial, there is a lib for Android too.
http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Comment: But the coding for JavaScript and android should be the same as far as the chat client sending the commands that the server is to be sent. Just the client user interface need different coding right since the interface building is dependent on what I am making for iOS, android or wp?

Comment: The commands that the server recognize are the same, however, the libraries to communicate and interact with the server  are different for iOS, android and wp.

Comment: ok i might be getting too deep ! @Rubens, did u mean that I have to use the different format of libraries for each system or really different libraries with no link with each other? if ure answer is the former than I assume that the commands (excluding the language used for in the IDE for ios, android, wp) are the same but just the different verions of libraries need to be downloaded and added as dependent libraries in the project (e.g asmack for android).!

Comment: I'm referring to libraries to comunicate and interact with XMPP server, I don't know If there is one library that works on Android, IOs and XP simultaneously. Check it out this list. http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/